# Ant: java.sql.SQLException: unable to open database file

Tags: ant, sqlite

I try to build my java project by Ant.

Windows 7 Professional (64 bit), Java 1.8.

I run my custom ant's target:

```
ant create-dist-win-lite -Denvironment=development
```

Here **build.xml**

```
<target name="create-dist-win-lite" description="Create WIN Lite dinstribute">
        <ac:var name="var.distribute.os.family" value="${prop.distribute.os.family.win}" />
        <ac:var name="var.distribute.version.type" value="${prop.distribute.version.lite}" />
        <ac:runtarget target="create-dist-os" />
</target>


    <target name="db:sqlite-exec-queries" depends="db:sqlite-set-variables,db:set-db-url">
        <echo message="var.data.dir.name=${var.data.dir.name}" />
        <echo message="var.db.driver=${var.db.driver}" />
        <echo message="var.db.current.url=${var.db.current.url}" />
        <echo message="var.db.lib.file.name=${var.db.lib.file.name}" />

        <delete dir="${var.data.dir.name}" />
        <mkdir dir="${var.data.dir.name}" />
        <sql driver="${var.db.driver}" url="${var.db.current.url}" userid="${var.db.user}" password="${var.db.pwd}" classpath="${lib.dir.name}/${var.db.lib.file.name}" delimiter="${var.db.delimiter}">
            <transaction src="${db.dir}/${var.db.type}/create-tables.sql" />
            <transaction src="${db.dir}/${var.db.type}/insert-data.sql" />
        </sql>
    </target>
```

As result, success created empty sqlite db file in *c:\dev\ca\dist\data\ca.db*.
But the folder *c:\dev\ca\dist\data* is READ only.

But target not success finish. When execute target *db:sqlite-exec-queries* I get error in this line:

```
<sql driver="${var.db.driver}" url="${var.db.current.url}" userid="${var.db.user}" password="${var.db.pwd}" classpath="${lib.dir.name}/${var.db.lib.file.name}" delimiter="${var.db.delimiter}">
```

Here full ant log:

```
db:sqlite-exec-queries:
     [echo] var.data.dir.name=dist/data
     [echo] var.db.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
     [echo] var.db.current.url=jdbc:sqlite://c:\dev\ca\dist\data/ca.db
     [echo] var.db.lib.file.name=sqlitejdbc-v056.jar
   [delete] Deleting directory c:\dev\ca\dist\data
    [mkdir] Created dir: c:\dev\ca\dist\data
      [sql] Executing resource: c:\dev\ca\db\sqlite\create-tables.sql
      [sql] Failed to execute:   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [AccountStatuses_Index] ON [AccountStatuses]( [CODE]  ASC )

BUILD FAILED
c:\dev\ca\build.xml:1396: java.sql.SQLException: unable to open database file
        at org.sqlite.DB.execute(DB.java:275)
        at org.sqlite.Stmt.exec(Stmt.java:56)
        at org.sqlite.Stmt.execute(Stmt.java:83)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.execSQL(SQLExec.java:775)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.runStatements(SQLExec.java:745)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec$Transaction.runTransaction(SQLExec.java:1055)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec$Transaction.access$000(SQLExec.java:985)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.execute(SQLExec.java:653)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.RunTargetTask.execute(RunTargetTask.java:48)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
```